# How to add images to PDF Page (predefined locations) using EO.PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are trying to have a placeholder of some sort (using EO.PDF), on the PDF pages (existing file). Not sure if we can use Form Field or some other element on the PDF file.

Then in ASP.NET C#, via code being able to add/display an image to wherever this placeholder appears on PDF pages.

The image will be a company logo.

Answer (score 0):

You can create bookmarks on any element.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    HtmlToPdfResult pdfResult = HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtml(htmlString, ms);
    HtmlElement element = pdfResult.HtmlDocument.GetElementById(elementId);
    string bookmarkName = "Your bookmark name";
    PdfBookmark bookmark = element.CreateBookmark(bookmarkName);
    bookmark.Destination = element.Location.CreateDestination();
    pdfResult.PdfDocument.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark);
    pdfResult.PdfDocument.Save(ms);
}
```